# How can I use <> operator and || operator inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have created an database file inside my asp.net application. Now from server explorer I tried to write a Stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData
(
@ID int,
@Name varchar(50),
    @Address varchar(50),
@bit BIT OUTPUT
)
as
begin
    declare @oldName as varchar(45)
    declare @oldAddress as varchar(45)

    set @oldName=(select EmployeeName from Employee where EmployeeName=@Name)
    set @oldAddress=(select Address from Employee where Address=@Address)

    if(@oldName <> @Name | @oldAddress <> @Address)
    insert into Employee(EmpID,EmployeeName,Address)values(@ID,@Name,@Address)
    SET @bit = 1
    END
```

But this is giving me an error when I am saving it like `Incorrect syntax near <`..

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... stuff like this is highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things wrong here

```
if(@oldName <> @Name | @oldAddress <> @Address)
```

Won't work - maybe try

```
if @oldName <> @Name OR @oldAddress <> @Address
```

Of course, this will never be true because of the way the two queries above (which could and should have just been one query assigning both variables) make sure that the variables are always equal.

I.e.:

```
set @oldName=(select EmployeeName from Employee where EmployeeName=@Name)
```

What can `@oldName` be, if not equal to `@Name`? (Okay, it could be `NULL`, but then `<>` is the wrong operator to use if `NULL` is what you're checking for)

I *think* that what you wanted to write here was:

```
select @oldName=EmployeeName,@oldAddress = Address from Employee where EmpID = @ID
```

Comment: Thanks Damien it works with `if @oldName <> @Name OR @oldAddress <> @Address`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `OR` and not `|`

You can also do this instead of querying and checking each value separately, this will insert new row if `name` and/or `address` do not match for given `empid`

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
select * from Employee 
where EmpID = @ID AND EmployeeName = @Name AND Address = @Address)
  insert into Employee(EmpID,EmployeeName,Address)values(@ID,@Name,@Address)
  SET @bit = 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use != instead of "<>" and you can use Or instead of "|".